# Swift how to check if API is NOT available

Tags: ios, swift4, cornerradius

I am applying corner radius to only top left and top right of a view. In `viewDidLoad()` I have:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
}
```

If iOS 11 is not available, the best way seems to do it in `draw(_ rect:)`. Since I have to override it outside `viewDidLoad()`, I want to do the following

```
if NOT #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.contentView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
        shapeLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        view.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
}
```

It is syntactically incorrect of course. What should I do?

Comment: You can use `else` part to fall back to older version `if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }`

Comment: I cannot override `draw(_ rect:)` in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

if you need to support earlier versions than iOS 11 then use `#available` inside the function `draw(rect:)` and use else part to apply logic on earlier versions

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {} else {
      let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.contentView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
      let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
      shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
      shapeLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
      view.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
 }
```

**Swift 5.6 and above: use #unavailable**

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
   if #unavailable(iOS 11, *) {
      let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.contentView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
      let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
      shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
      shapeLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
      view.layer.mask = shapeLayer
   }     
}
```

Comment: I expected something not so ugly

Comment: Consider also ```guard #available(iOS 11, *) ...```

Comment: As of Swift 5.6 you can now write `if #unavailable(iOS 12)` to execute code if the iOS is below 12.0.

Comment: updated the answer to use #unavailable for Swift 5.6